# Android Layer List Drawable Move Adjust Item Position

Tags: android, material-design, android-xml, android-drawable

How to positon the `<item>` inside `<layer-list>` Drawable? Thanks for any help.

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_uncheck" />    //24dp from vector assset

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/check_mark" />    //24dp from vector asset

</layer-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally choose to modify the **SVG** image to meet my needs, following is the process:

1. Go to ["https://materialdesignicons.com/"](https://materialdesignicons.com/) -> find image -> download SVG image.
2. Go to "https://editor.method.ac/" -> "File" -> "Open SVG..." -> choose SVG file -> "Open".
3. Adjust canvas width and height on the right panel.
4. Adjust the positon of the imported SVG image.
5. "File" -> "Save Image..." -> rename file -> "Download".
6. Import the SVG image to Android Studio as vector asset.

Answer (score 1):

Using `android:left` and `android:top` of the item tag for the check mark will shift the check up and to the right, but it will also shrink the check mark which I don't think you are looking for.

I can think of two other ways to approach this: The first is to just edit the check mark drawable to shift it. You can do this with an editor such as InkScape and there are others. You may need to adjust the overall size slightly to accommodate the shifted check mark. I prefer this approach.

The second approach would be to write a custon [LayerDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable) that would override the `draw()` method to offset the check mark. I might prefer this method if this is something you may need to do with other drawables. If not, I suggest just doing the first suggestion.

If you are willing to abandon the layer drawable, you can also accomplish what you need with a couple of views using translateX and translateY. I am sure that there are other approaches, too.